# disable submit button when input fields is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I want to disable submit button when 4 input fields are nulls

```
<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1">
<input type="text" name="val2" id="val2">
<input type="text" name="val3" id="val3">
<input type="text" name="val4" id="val4">
```

submit button

```
<input name="contact" type="submit" id="contact" value="Update" style="padding:5px" class="sendButton" disabled />
```

I am using

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);

            $('#val1').keyup(function(){
                if($(this).val().length !=0){
                    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', true);        
                }
            })
            $('#val2').keyup(function(){
                if($(this).val().length !=0){
                    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', true);        
                }
            })
            $('#val3').keyup(function(){
                if($(this).val().length !=0){
                    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', true);        
                }
            })
            $('#val4').keyup(function(){
                if($(this).val().length !=0){
                    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', true);        
                }
            })
        });
        </script>
```

I think I am using wrongly. I put all ids in one function.

```
 $('#val1','#val2','#val3','#val4').keyup(function(){
```

this code is not working . any suggestion. how to use & and condition(val1 &val2 & val3 &val4) in these function?.

Comment: This should not be tagged as php

Answer (score 2):

The way I would try and solve this is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#val1").keyup(function(event) {
        validateInputs();
    });

    $("#val2").keyup(function(event) {
        validateInputs();
    });

    $("#val3").keyup(function(event) {
        validateInputs();
    });

    $("#val4").keyup(function(event) {
        validateInputs();
    });

    function validateInputs(){
        var disableButton = false;

        var val1 = $("#val1").val();
        var val2 = $("#val2").val();
        var val3 = $("#val3").val();
        var val4 = $("#val4").val();

        if(val1.length == 0 || val2.length == 0 || val3.length == 0 || val4.length == 0)
            disableButton = true;

        $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', disableButton);
    }
</script>
```

This way you will have a single place for checking your logic and not having to maintain it at N number of places if you diced to add more inputs later. And also a bit better solution would be to give your inputs the same class so you could do something like

```
$(".myInputs").keyup(function(event){
    validateInputs();
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/moj2dnup/

Comment: But you put the checks inside an OR condition, this will disable the button if only one of the inputs has no value. I think OP was looking for an && check (all 4 inputs empty, disable the button)

Comment: Maybe, if that is the case he can always just replace `||` (or) with `&&` (and) and get a desired output.

Comment: @IgorIlic within your if conditional, you should add an `else` condition : `else { disableButton = false; }`, otherwise the button will still disabled even if all of the inputs are filled up

Comment: @HastaDhana I have switched from global to a local variable in my example, this way the value of the `disableButton` variable will be reset on each check. So the button will be able to toggle enabled/disabled state properly

Comment: shall i add any js or simply use <script> tag

Comment: @anbesivam just include your jquery library and wrap this code inside of a `<script>` tag. I have update my code, to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [pattern attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-input-pattern) you would also need to use the [required attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/forms.html#attr-input-required) otherwise an input field with an empty value will be excluded from [constraint validation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constraint-validation). This will prevent your form from being submitted, however, it won't disable your button.

Example:

```
<input pattern=".{5,}"   required title="5 character minimum">
<input pattern=".{5,10}" required title="between 5 and 10 characters">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);               
       $('.txtValues').keyup(function(){
       var checkNull=false;
      $('.txtValues').each(function(index,input){
        if($(this).val().length !=0)checkNull=true;
      });
      if(checkNull){
         $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false); 
      }else{
         $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', true); 
      }
   });

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            
  <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" class="txtValues">
  <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2" class="txtValues">
  <input type="text" name="val3" id="val3" class="txtValues">
  <input type="text" name="val4" id="val4" class="txtValues">    
  
<input name="contact" type="submit" id="contact" value="Update" style="padding:5px" class="sendButton" disabled />
```

Use a common css class for all inputs. Loop through inputs using $.each and check all values are null.